# RoboCopy Copy To another server in same domain

Tags: robocopy

I would like to `copy/duplicate` folder data from  ServerA to ServerB in same domain (Server PRD to DRC)

For Example:

Source Folder A on server 10.192.10.1

**C :\Folder A**

Destination  Folder B on server 10.194.10.1

**C :\Folder B**

Run on domain : corp

How can I write a batch script to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
@echo off
REM Filename: sync-dirs.bat
REM generic robocopy backup script that DELETES (purge) files on the 
REM Destination if they are also deleted on the Source! (i.e. sync/mirror).

set ROBOCOPY=c:\windows\system32\robocopy.exe
set SRC=\\10.192.10.1\shared_folder_A
set DST=\\10.194.10.1\shared_folder_B

%ROBOCOPY% %SRC% %DST% /MIR /R:10 /W:1 /ETA
```

Hope this helps..